# Microsoft SQL and SSAS rigid relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

I have the following error :
" Errors in the OLAP storage engine: Rigid relationships between attributes cannot be changed during incremental processing of a dimension. The error occurred when processing attribute 'Month'.. Source attribute: 'Date'. Key column value(s) of the source attrbibute: '112234' ".

What happened :
I made insert yesterday with record '112234' in the source, after which I processed the dimension, but I realized I was wrong. I did an update in the source, changing '112234' to '112233', after which I tried to process the dimension again, but received the above error message.
I thought that was because of incremental issue. So I waited for today to do the insert with today's key, '112235', but at the dimesion processing I got the same error as before, even though the value is higher than the one from yesterday.

How can I get rid of '112234' and to get the dimension to take the latest value, '112235', and increment from there? --> I don't want to change the relationships.

Comment: English please.

Comment: Stackoverflow este destinat doar întrebărilor scrise în limba engleză. (https://translate.google.com vă poate ajuta. )

Comment: I have edited the question. It was my mistake. Sorry about that.